# When does one use "stehend bleiben"?

Tags: word-usage

Translating this into German:

> He remained standing very still for 5 minutes,

can one say:

> Er blieb 5 Minuten länger sehr still **stehend**?

While I know that "**stehen**" might be more usual, I submit the following examples from DWDS in support of the possibility:

Die Zeit, 05.05.1995, Nr. 19
Sechstagerennen, Boxkämpfe und Tennisturniere waren seine bevorzugte Sparte beim Berliner Tagesblatt; als er mit einem Male selbst herumgeboxt und zum Verfolgerrennen in die ausweglose Bahn geschickt wurde, blieb er gleichwohl neben sich **stehend** und versuchte, sich zuzuschauen.

Der Tagesspiegel, 18.11.2002
Dann bliebe der Diktator abermals im Ring: angeschlagen, aber **stehend**.

Berliner Zeitung, 28.04.1997
Sie blieben **stehend** bis zum Ende, als die Märchenszene aus "Jakob der Lügner" gezeigt wurde.

Kloster Eberbach. In: Wikipedia: Die freie Enzyklopädie. 14.08.2022.
Die meisten der Gebäude blieben jedoch leer **stehend**.

Hans Oschmann. In: Wikipedia: Die freie Enzyklopädie. 25.03.2022.
Hier blieb er, abermals in Russland **stehend**, bis Anfang 1943 und wurde dann in die Führerreserve versetzt.

Mandschurische Tanne. In: Wikipedia: Die freie Enzyklopädie. 27.11.2020.
Im Bestand bleibt ihr Stamm frei, während sie solitär **stehend** bis zum Grund beastet bleibt.

Kursächsische Distanzsäule Oberwiesenthal. In: Wikipedia: Die freie Enzyklopädie. 22.06.2018.
In diesem Zusammenhang wurde auch das Postament der Distanzsäule mit einem zeitgenössischen Sinnspruch (Wandrer bleibe sinnend **stehend** an dem Merkstein alter Zeit [...]) versehen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not wrong, but not very idiomatic either.

You would normally use the participle in combination with a different verb, to describe the state or a property of the subject ("er" is "stehend"):

Idiomatic use:

> Sehr still stehend(,) beobachtete er noch für 5 Minuten die Menschen auf dem Marktplatz.

If you use "stehend" with "bleiben" as the verb, that's very close to the verb "stehenbleiben" (to stop, to stall, to stand still, to remain standing), but grammatically clearly different, so your readers might be a bit stumped on why you're not using "stehenbleiben".

By separating the participle construction from the main clause using a comma, you can make clearer that you're intentionally using "blieb" as a separate strong verb, like "remained" in the English version.

> Er blieb 5 Minuten länger, sehr still stehend. 
> (*or:* Er blieb, 5 Minuten länger sehr still stehend.)

Answer (score 1):

[English Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bleiben) explains the different usages best:

"bleiben" can be used

1. with the infinitive of a limited set of verbs,
   including "stehen", "sitzen": "Sie bleibt stehen"
2. with a predicate adjective or predicate noun: "Sie bleibt stehend"
3. bare; here "stehend" can be a free adverbial: "Sie bleibt, stehend."

(1.) is the normal form to use with "stehen". It means "keep on standing". It is, however, impossible to use it with any figurative meaning of "stehen".
So those are impossible:

> **Er bleibt zur Verfügung stehen.* 
> **Er bleibt neben sich stehen.*

So we have to switch to the less natural way to say it, using (2.). In your
examples we have "leer stehend", "neben sich stehend".

In the example with the dictator, "Hans Oschmann" (hier refers to "Nachrichtenaufklärung 3") and with the "Tanne", *stehend* is an adverbial
and the predicative part is something else.

In (2.) "stehend bleiben" the focus is more on "standing" (and not sitting etc.). While in "stehen bleiben" the focus is more on "bleiben" (and not going): This explains the

> Sie blieben stehend bis zum Ende, [...].

example.

Now to your translation: Firstly, "stillstehen" is not perceived as "still"+"stehen", so "sehr still stehen" is only perceived as "standing very *quietly*". And "5 Minuten lang" (for 5 minutes) is different to "5 Minuten länger" (5 minutes longer). But aside from that: Yes, you can say:

> Er blieb 5 Minuten sehr ruhig stehend.